# Any help connecting two sentences? (for subtitle creation)

Tags: particle-と

I'm adding subtitles (for a friend) to a Saiyuki drama CD accompanied by a video. The video has captions at different points to explain what is going on in the opening scene:

00:22　－引き返してきたヘイゼルとー

00:29　ー再び見まえた三蔵一行ー

00:35　－一時の休息の間にー

00:55　ー悟空が何者か攻撃を受けるー

01:00　ー三蔵の眼の前で、－

The first two parts are where I'm having issues. It seems the と here is connecting the nouns ヘイゼル and 三蔵一行, but they are described by 引き返してきた and 再び見まえた. In my quest to translate these into English though, it sounds wrong to put, "Hazel, who came back, and the Sanzo party, which ran into him, were taking a quick break when Goku was attacked in front of Sanzo's eyes."

Somehow, I'm missing something. It could be with the whole 見まえた part. I feel like ～まえた is しまった in some dialect, but I could be wrong.

I'm not asking for a translation, of course. I'm just trying to figure out what is going on here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{ [ (引き返してきた →) ヘイゼル ] と再び見まえた → } 三蔵一行
Sanzo party { ← which confronted [ Hazel ( ← who came back ) ] }
```

I think 見まえる here is probably a (common) misspelling for [まみえる](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) (=meet, confront). This と is simply an ordinary particle used with まみえる/会う/待ち合わせをする/etc. (eg 明日彼**と**会う = "meet him tomorrow")

Of course due to the different word order of the two languages, the literal translation above won't work in your case. Rephrase it as you like, for example, "Hazel's Return" and "Sanzo Party Confronts Hazel Again".

Comment: 説明ありがとうございました！I figured a literal translation wouldn't work anyway, so no biggie. I got that part handled. Thanks again!